# How to make an "if( variable1 < X more or less Y)"?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm currently creating a little game, and I need to create a condition.

In pseudo-code, it would look like something like this :

```
if (a < x with x included in [b -10; b +10]) 
{
    then c = 2
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this ?

I know it may not be really clear, so ask me further details if you didn't understand.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking "if(y < x), give or take 10 from x"?

Comment: Are you saying that `a` needs to be greater than `x` AND that `x` needs to be between -10 and 10 inclusive?

Comment: Mhm sorry I'm not clear as I guessed.. I would like to verify if x is included in b-10 and b+10.
Like, for example if x = 5 and b = 3, then the condition is verified.

Comment: That means that `x >= b-10 && x <= b+10`

Comment: And what about `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(a < x && x >= b-10 && x <= b + 10){

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't understand how I didn't figure that out by myself... Time to go back to work !

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more concise way to write it is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

if (a < x && abs(x-b) <= 10) {
    c = 2;
}
```

If your variables are something other than `int`, you can use `labs, llabs, fabs, fabsf, fabsl`, as appropriate.

This can fail in the event of integer overflow (e.g. if `x`,`b` are 32-bit `int`s, and they differ by more than 2^31), so don't use it if that is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You want the condition to be true if `a` is less than `x` AND `x` is greater than or equal to `b-10` AND `x` is less than or equal to `b+10`.  You would write that as:

```
if ((a < x) && (x >= (b-10)) && (x <=(b+10))) {
    c = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly `a` , `b` and `C` are constant variables and you want to assign value in C. Then this will be like

```
if( a < X && ( b - 10 <= X && b + 10 >= X ) {
    C = 2;
}
```